# calling wizard method inside another method

Tags: c#, .net, methods, wizard

I have to methods

```
Barcodereader (object sender, EventArgs e)
```

and the other

```
protected void RadWizard1_NextButtonClick(object sender, WizardEventArgs e)
```

As you can imagine from the methods name the first one serves to read a barcode and the other to pass to the next step in a wizard.

What I want to do is that when the barcode is read and found to call the

```
protected void RadWizard1_NextButtonClick(object sender, WizardEventArgs e)
```

so will be executed the code and pass me to the next step.
I have tryed the classic

```
 Barcodereader (object sender, EventArgs e) {
     //do something
      if (!opMsg.IsError) {
         RadWizard1_NextButtonClick(object sender, WizardEventArgs e)
         }
     }
```

but gives me error saying

> 'WizardEventArgs e is a type but used as a variable'

Any idea where I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't write the argument types in the call:

```
 Barcodereader (object sender, EventArgs e) {
     //do something
      if (!opMsg.IsError) {
         RadWizard1_NextButtonClick(sender, e as WizardEventArgs) // arguments WITHOUT types
         }
     }
```

**But note** that `e` is of type `EventArgs`. I cast this using the `as` operator in my example, because `RadWizard1_NextButtonClick` expects `WizardEventArgs`.
If `e` is not of type `WizardEventArgs`, `null` will be passed.

Comment: Just a note - `e` is of type `EventArgs`, but the called method expects a `WizardEventArgs`

Comment: Error 6 The best overloaded method match for 'Card.DeliveryWizard.RadWizard1_NextButtonClick(object, Telerik.Web.UI.WizardEventArgs)' has some invalid arguments and  Error 7 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.EventArgs' to 'Telerik.Web.UI.WizardEventArgs'    Giving me this errors now

Comment: @Rene sorry for bothering again. just noticed that parameter e as WizardeventArgs is returning e as EventArgs of the first method and shouldnt be like that. Any idea why?